# Как правильно задавать вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Не знаю, можно ли задавать такие вопросы тут. Пытался задать вопрос на Мете, но не вышло. Недавно мой вопрос про Java и Android Studio был закрыт по причине "не по теме". Вопрос заключался в том, что при открытии приложения не отображался элемент, который должен был отображаться. Я приложил скриншоты, думал, всё будет понятно. Но мой вопрос был закрыт. Вот что было там написано:

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Желаемо поведение понятно - элемент должен отображаться. 
Конкретная проблема понятна - элемент не отображается. 
Код был на скриншоте, хотя вряд ли в нём была необходимость.
Почему вопрос был закрыт - для меня загадка.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: А вообще чем придумывать новые вопросы, подумайте над своим, всё то время, которое могли не тратить на новые.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Нет смысла думать над своим вопросом, когда он закрыт.

Comment: "Пытался задать вопрос на Мете, но не вышло" --- как много непонятных звуков в этом пространном "не вышло"

Comment: @user498020, вам кто-то запрещает его улучшить? или задать новый(свой старый обдуманный ^^)?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский новорегам без рейтинга вроде и нельзя писать на мету, раньше так было...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не в этом суть комментария была)) но вы конечно ответили за него...))

Comment: Вопрос был закрыт по причине того что "код был на скриншоте", одно из правил - код непосредственно в вопросе. Самого вопроса я не видел, и не могу сказать точнее чем это предположение. Так же возможная причина - вы не привели минимального примера для воспроизведения проблемы....

Comment: @user498020  "Код был на скриншоте" --- это неправильно.. Вот представьте себе, что вам нужно разработать систему чатов в проекте....точнее доделать. Разработчик, который начинал делать - уволился.... Теперь вы продолжаете его дело......и......вместо файлов с кодом, вам дают скрины..... как вам?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский простите, не смог удержаться, а в чем проблема то если разработка так построена xD https://tproger.ru/devnull/ms-paint-ide/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, У меня не вышло задать вопрос на Мете, потому что у меня не получается там зарегистрироваться.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков что значит "не привели минимального примера для воспроизведения проблемы" и как это надо делать?

Comment: В правилах всё это есть, стоит их почитать если имеете желание получать ответы на свои вопросы... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков 

Comment: `как это надо делать` - в идеале нужно вставить в вопрос минимальное количество кода, который можно скопировать, запустить и увидеть проблему. `Код был на скриншоте, хотя вряд ли в нём была необходимость` - если что-то работает не так как вы ожидаете, то очень возможно, что вы что-то не так делаете. Без кода невозможно понять, что вы делаете не так. А иногда и что вы вообще делаете. Тут ведь важны детали, а словесное описание это соовсем не то, что код.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема сильно глубже, чем кажется на первый взгляд. Давайте для понимания разделим вопросы и отвечающих на три условных категории, как это принято у программистов - джуны, мидлы и сеньйоры.

Допустим, задается вопрос уровня джун. Для джуна он сложен и важен. Он не может его взять с наскока (если только не повезет). Он иногда даже не может объяснить его полностью - ему не хватает "словаря". Приходит старый сеньйор, для которого проблема насколько очевидна, насколько и то, что он сеньйор и не понимает, почему такой вопрос возник, почему вопрошающий не захотел разобраться, это же так элементарно! Но для вопрошающего этот вопрос уже на пределе возможностей. И тут может быть несколько вариантов - кто то сжалится и напишет ответ (но как показывает опыт, обычно такие ответы минусуют, при чем как сеньоры (что бы не потакали лентяям), так и мидлы (которые хоть и видят один-два варианта ответа, но обычно не видят всей картины миры и считают, что ответ неверный, потому что не совпадает с тем, что они знают), но это редкость). Второй вариант - просто проигнорируют вопрос (далеко не самый плохой вариант) и третий, типичный вариант - просто заминсуют/закроют с любым вариантом, потому что им <подставьте любую доступную причину и найдется десяток объяснений почему именно она такая>.

Второй вариант - сложный сеньйорский вопрос. Джуны тут просто молчат (очевидно), мидлы уже готовы поучится (а может и померятся коментариями), а сеньоры... а они иногда отвечают, а иногда просто молчат. Почему? да это сложно, нужно разбираться, автор мог бы и сам разобраться, раз уж задал такой вопрос и всем рассказать, а мы тут уже бы посмотрели, поголосовали.

Иногда такие "сеньйорские вопросы" возникают у новичков ([вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425884/c-int-ptr-new-int0) хороший кандидат в такие вопросы) и тут возникает дилемма - написать хороший ответ - заплюсуют, но не поймет вопрошающий, написать ответ уровня вопрошающего - ему поможешь, но ответ скорее всего заминусуют и забросают отходами производства (знаю по своему опыту). Собственно сам текущий вопрос и есть примером такого вопроса. Достаточно почитать комментарии.

вот например

> "Пытался задать вопрос на Мете, но не вышло" --- как много непонятных звуков в этом пространном "не вышло"
> @Алексей-Шиманский

да, человек пытался, но он не может объяснить, почему это не вышло. Но нужно ли критиковать за это? может стоит спросить по другому? где то так " а как выглядит это "не вышло"? выключился комп, показало сообщение на экране (какое именно, может скриншот есть?)". А может мама пришла и выключила комп... Как потом оказалось - просто зарегистрироваться не смог, но коментов настрочили... ух.

Третий вопрос - мидл-вопрос. Хороший пример - [вопрос с линковкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546/%d0%a1%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b). На такой вопрос есть много ответов под разные случаи, разобран хорошо вдоль и впоперек. Таких вопросов не много, но ответы прописаны хорошо и можно часто закрывать дубликатом. Но тут другая проблема - для начинающий обычно совсем непонятно, когда просто закрывают дубликатом, какой из 100500 ответов подходит ему. но очень редко закрывающие дописывают подсказку куда именно смотреть.

Теперь перейдем собственно к вопросу. Как задавать вопрос, что бы на него ответили. А похоже нет такого правила. Это часто везенье - просто повезло включить все необходимое, что бы подходящий человек открыл вопрос и у него было время и желание написать ответ. А может рядом пробегать человек, которому только что наступили на ногу в трамвае и он хочет выпустить пар (сам того не понимая) и нажать минус (благое дело, это анонимно и никто не увидит, какой он "крутой" и всех "наказал").

Что же делать, если есть вопросы, а отвечать никто не хочет/не может? Есть несколько способов.

- начать писать этот вопрос на SO. В процессе написания вопросов (как минимум на английской версии) предлагает варианты "похожих вопросов". Даже сам заголовок вопроса уже запустит этот механизм. И смотреть в предлагаемые ответы. Иногда, среди них находятся хорошие варианты, которые почему то не находятся поиском.
- прочитать наконец то хоть какую то книгу по теме. Да, я понимаю, это сложно, книги толстые, в них ничего не понятно, но нужно использовать правильную методику. Не нужно попытаться прочитать и все понять. Надо читать как художественную литератору. здесь определение - прочитаю дважды, здесь пошло рассуждение, почему и как - просмотрю по диагонали, поймаю ключевые слова. А потом, через какое то время возникнет "о, я это видел в той книге, сейчас найду и ещё раз прочитаю". И это работает, реально работает.
- использовать желтую уточку. Но это для очень сложных вопросов. И объяснить это уточке. В какой то момент либо ответ будет понятен, либо уточка его расскажет, но это уже психиатрия.

Из своего опыта. Была у меня одна проблема с приложением на телефоне, вроде очевидна, а ответа загуглить не мог. В принципе. Пошел к саппорту (это саппорт в той компании, где я тогда работал) и говорю "видите проблему на экране?" "да". " а как бы простой американец это назвал?" и мне подбросили пару слов (приличных). После чего вдруг в гугле начали находися ответы. И самое интересное - на некоторые страницы я и раньше заходил, но ответа "не видел". Потому что "не владел словарем" (это не просто знание слов). А как только узнал - сразу стало понятно.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0vG7.png по этому поводу пост с багом на мете оставить или я что-то о Вас не знаю?))

Comment: "да, человек пытался, но он не может объяснить, почему это не вышло" --- для того, чтобы написать, что именно не вышло - не надо навыков синьора в какой-либо области или 100% знания функционала сайта. Для объяснения нужен просто (сюрприз!) мозг. Если человеку лет 7-8, тогда ок, можно подумать, что ему сложно по-взрослому выразить мысль. ............. user498020 - если тебе до 8 лет включительно - сори за комментарий.

Comment: @МихаилРебров я тоже это видел. На мете это точно первый ответ. Вот оно и сходит с ума. Алексей, даже если человек взрослый, то все равно ему может быть сложно сформулировать вопрос. А людей, которые могут это сделать ой как мало. Просто представьте себе, что Вы разбираетесь в квантовой физике или ракетостроении. Но есть и противоположный случай, когда человек думает, что он разбирается в теме, а по факту - нет (диванные эксперты).

Comment: Я (как всегда уже...) могу добавить только один совет -- не надо закрывать вопросы, вообще не надо, толко если этот вопрос не откровенный бред. Всем новичкам (и не только) сразу станет легче

Comment: @KoVadim так я не про вопрос говорил, а про что-то, не относящееся к проф области. С проф областью я согласен. А вот с обычным описанием ситуации - тут не вижу проблем. Например если на работу опаздываю то начальнику можно написать "я опаздываю", что итак ясно, когда на часах 11, а надо быть к 9, а можно написать "я опаздываю, тут авария на дороге и все стоЯт в пробке" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  ......вот с "попытался и не вышло" та же история

Comment: в наше время иногда очень сложно провести границу между "проф областью" и "не проф областью".

Comment: вот заработал я тут два плюса - а в карму оно не добавилось. Это мета сломана или так задумано? вроде раньше у меты отдельно считались балы...

Comment: @KoVadim На мете голоса за и против только показывают согласны ли с вашим мнением или нет, потому в карму ничего не добавляется :) Если бы тут считалось отдельно, то у вас тут было бы 0 баллов в начале. [Выдержка из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): Голосования на Мете не влияют на вашу репутация на основном сайте, а репутация на Мете соответствует вашей репутации на Stack Overflow на русском. Общаясь на Мете, вы можете получить дополнительные знаки. Для участия в обсуждениях на Мете вам необходимо иметь 5 баллов репутации.

Comment: ох, ох. Вот Но при этом значок "новый участник" у меня висит. Вот верь после этого справке...